# Rails 3.2, jQuery 1.7.1 link to assets/images broken

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My setup includes ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2 and jQuery 1.7.1. I found that jQuery is sending requests to /assets/images/image_file.png instead of just /assets/image_file.png which results into broken link as shown in the image below:

[image: jQery link to image broken. other css,js and images files are referenced in assets correctly.]

I know from [Asset Organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) that Rails look for appropriate folder in assets for js, css and image files. So I know that it should be looking in a subdirectory 'images' for the image referenced as /assets/images. I created an subdirectory images within in assets/images (app/assets/images/images) and copied the referenced image there and it worked.

But shouldn't jQuery reference the images correctly in assets directory. Here is the jQuery code referenced by the error with line producing error highlighted:

[image: jQuery code resulting in broken link, line producing error highlighted.]

Is there any configuration parameter that needs to be set in application.rb or environment files to set the asset path for jQuery? Or any other way to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your issue or not but could you search around your css files and let me know which file and place `ui-bg_glass_80_d7ebf9_1x400.png` has been written?

Answer (score 1):

Search around CSS under your project & replace `images/ui-bg_glass_80_d7ebf9_1x400.png` to `ui-bg_glass_80_d7ebf9_1x400.png`, Hopefully it works.

Comment: Thanks. Searched in the project and found that issue is in jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css file. All the link to images starts with `images/`. For now I'll replace all links, but I think it should be resolved either in Rails so that jquery-ui or other css files could be used out of the box.

Comment: welcome, its not issue with Rails + jQuery, its a issue because of custom css used with jQuery UI so we have to take care of it ourself. Same issue happen with any technology because its custom CSS. Anyway, good to know that you find your solution... :)

Comment: I replaced all the occurrences of `url(images/image_file_name)` to `url(image_file_name)` and also tried `url(/images/image_file_name)` in jquery-ui custom css file. But it still results in broken image link with the same code reference to jquery.js file as shown in the question.

Comment: @Zeeshan - as I told you its quite difficult to understand/resolve issue using just above information, Its just my guessing what can be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css` file expects its images to be in an `images` directory relative to CSS file itself.
However, the Rails 3 asset pipeline moves the CSS file to a different location so the image path no longer works.

The standard layout if you download the jquery ui 'start' theme is:

```
stylesheets/start/
stylesheets/start/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css
stylesheets/start/images/
```

But the asset pipeline arranges it like this:

```
stylesheets/
stylesheets/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css
stylesheets/start/images/
```

So the relative path of `/images/ui-bg_glass_80_d7ebf9_1x400.png` no longer works.

I have a workaround which is to add an Alias directive into my Apache config:

```
Alias /assets/images "<path to site>/public/assets/start/images"
```

This assumes your assets are sym-linked into the public directory.
You could change that path to point directly to wherever your assets are served from.

This is a bit of a kludge as if I ever decide to change themes (highly unlikely) I'll need to update my Apache config.
But for me it's better than rewriting the CSS file to change the paths as that becomes a pain when upgrading.

Hope this helps.